# Change key for expanding HTML tag name to element

Tags: html, pycharm

*I recently started using PyCharm for editing HTML files as part of a larger Python project. Thus I may be lacking the necessary experience to see the bigger picture this feature fits into.*

PyCharm's HTML mode has this cool feature where it will expand a CSS selector to a complete HTML tag which would be matched by that selector. The main use, as far as I can see, is to quickly create arbitrary HTML tags with some common attributes already set:

`span.note.important`

Pressing the tab key at the end of that selector would translate it into the following fragment with the cursor placed inside the element:

`<span class="note important"></span>`

The problem is that I've currently mapped the tab key (and I think it was already by default) to completing live templates and jumping between template variables. Thus invoking a template, filling in the first variable and then pressing the tab key would not jump to the next variable (or to the end of the template), it would instead fill the template parameter with HTML-garbage!

I can see that sometimes this behaviour would be useful, even inside template variables, but I would like to have the choice when it happens.

Is there a way to change the key which is used to invoke the CSS-selector-to-HTML-magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Emmet`
2. Change `Expand abbreviation with` from `Tab` to something else.

   [image]

   (NOTE: this screenshot is made from PhpStorm, but it is the same for PyCharm)

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/enabling-emmet-support.html?search=emmet

Comment: Thank you! "Emmet" was the keyword I needed to know.